# Returning a complex series of commands via ajax (or perhaps restructuring it once returned through ajax)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I currently have a function that looks like this:

```
function getEvents($weekNumStart, $weekNumEnd){
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    if (!$mysqli) {
        die('There was a problem connecting to the database.');
    }
    else {
        if ($weekNumEnd == '') {
            $weekNumEnd = $weekNumStart;
        }
        $Group = $_SESSION['Group'];
        $query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT EventID, DAYOFWEEK(Start) AS wday, Events.Start, HOUR(Start) AS sHour, HOUR(End) AS eHour, Events.End, Events.Group, Events.Unit, Type, Room, Lecturer, Cancelled, StartName FROM Events, Week WHERE StartName >= '$weekNumStart' AND StartName <= '$weekNumEnd' AND Events.Start >= StartWeek AND Events.Start <=EndWeek AND (Events.Group = '$Group' OR Events.Group = '');");
        $query->execute();
        $query->bind_result($eventID, $dayofweek, $startDateTime, $startHour, $endHour, $endDateTime, $group, $unit, $type, $room, $lecturer, $cancelled, $weekName);
        $data_arr = array();
        while ($query->fetch()){
            $data_arr[] = array(
               $eventID, $dayofweek, $startDateTime, $startHour, $endHour, $endDateTime, $group, $unit, $type, $room, $lecturer, $cancelled, $weekName
            );
        }
        return $data_arr; //
    }
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

This function works how I want it to. I currently manipulate it like this:

```
if (!isset($weekNumEnd)){
        $weekNumEnd = '';
    }
    $data = getEvents($weekNumStart, $weekNumEnd);
    foreach($data as $day) {
        for($i=0;$i<7;$i++){
            for($j=9;$j<=18;$j++){
                if ($day[1] == $i && $day[3] == $j){
                    $unit = $day[7];
                    $type = $day[8];
                    $room = $day[9];
                    if ($i == 2){
                    ?>
                    <script>
                    var mon<?=$j?>unit = '<?=$unit?>';
                    var mon<?=$j?>type = '<?=$type?>';
                    var mon<?=$j?>room = '<?=$room?>';
                    $('#mon-<?=$j?>').append(
                        "<p>"+mon<?=$j?>unit+"<br>"+mon<?=$j?>type+"<br>"+mon<?=$j?>room+"</p>"
                    );
                    </script>
                    <?php
                    if (($day[4] - $day[3]) > 1) {
                        for($q=($day[3]+1);$q<$day[4];$q++){
                        ?>
                        <script>
                            var mon<?=$q?>unit = '<?=$unit?>';
                            var mon<?=$q?>type = '<?=$type?>';
                            var mon<?=$q?>room = '<?=$room?>';
                            $('#mon-<?=$q?>').append(
                                "<p>"+mon<?=$q?>unit+"<br>"+mon<?=$q?>type+"<br>"+mon<?=$q?>room+"</p>"
                            );
                        </script>
                        <?php
                        }
                    }
                }
```

The problem is. I obviously cannot run it in real time to constantly update the events list whenever the week or whatever is changed.

So to fix it, I decided to try using Ajax. So far I have this:

```
function getEvents() {
        var data = 'Events=Yes';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "functions/updateWeek.php", 
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(html) {
                    alert(html.returned_val);
            }
    });
}
```

And I have this to return:

```
if($_POST['Events'] == "Yes"){
    $weekNumStart = $_SESSION['startWeek'];
    $weekNumEnd = $_SESSION['endWeek'];
    $data = getEvents($weekNumStart, $weekNumEnd);
    echo json_encode(array('returned_val' => $data));
}
```

And this...sort of works. at least that is to say it returns the data in one ugly great chunk.

The thing is I can no longer manipulate it as I did before as above:

```
data = getEvents($weekNumStart, $weekNumEnd);
    foreach($data as $day) {
        for($i=0;$i<7;$i++){
            for($j=9;$j<=18;$j++){
                if ($day[1] == $i && $day[3] == $j){
                    $unit = $day[7];
                    $type = $day[8];
                    $room = $day[9];
                    if ($i == 2){
                    ?>
                    <script>
                    var mon<?=$j?>unit = '<?=$unit?>';
                    var mon<?=$j?>type = '<?=$type?>';
                    var mon<?=$j?>room = '<?=$room?>';
                    $('#mon-<?=$j?>').append(
                        "<p>"+mon<?=$j?>unit+"<br>"+mon<?=$j?>type+"<br>"+mon<?=$j?>room+"</p>"
                    );
                    </script>
```

That is to say - I don't know how to re-manipulate it when I've called the information back through ajax. Would I rewrite all of the above in an entirely javascript fashion? Is there a more logical way of doing this that I do not know/understand? Or is there a way I can just make that code work (complete with php and javascript) in that different window, and have it send it all back, correct through ajax, to automatically work on the page without having to rewrite it once the info is pulled back through ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's enough to use json_encode($data) and you'll get the array from AJAX.

Second, check it with Firebug, as you should get structured data, not big chunk.

alert() just tries to print everything as single string, that's all

```
for( var i = 0; i < html.length; i++ )
    // do something with html[i]
```

Comment: Ohhh!

Of course. Thank you. That single-handedly fixed all of my issues.